# Search Bar for an ExpandableListView

Tags: listview, search, xamarin, xamarin.android, expandablelistview

In my code I use a custom ExpandableListViewAdapter use BaseExpandableListAdapter. I am trying to filter my parent groups when someone searches for a specific word in the search bar. I was trying to use ITextWatcher however, when I use .Filter with my ExpandableListViewAdapter mAdapter my code wont build. I also can't use InvokeFilter(s) to filter out the parents. Can someone please help? Thank you in advance!

Again I am trying to filter through the parents; not the children. This is my main:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Net;
using Java.Lang;
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using Java.Util;
using System.Threading;
using Org.Json;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Views;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using RestSharp.Extensions.MonoHttp;
using Android.Text;

namespace DictionaryE
{
    [Activity(Label = "DictionaryE", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/logo")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private ExpandableListView list;
    private ExpandableListViewAdapter mAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<string> adapter;
    private int length;
    private List<string> group= new List<string>();
    private string[] names;
    private Dictionary<string, List<string>> Mapout = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    private SearchView searchBar;
    private View.IOnClickListener listener;


    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        ActionBar.Hide();
        // Set Views
        searchBar = FindViewById<SearchView>(Resource.Id.searchBar);
        list = FindViewById<ExpandableListView>(Resource.Id.lv);
        //Set Groups
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string json = client.DownloadString("********************");
        JSONArray myarray = new JSONArray(json);
        length = myarray.Length();
        names = new string[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            JSONObject Element = myarray.GetJSONObject(i);
            names[i] = Element.GetString("name");
        }
        setData(out mAdapter);
        list.SetAdapter(mAdapter);

        mAdapter.Filter.InvokeFilter();

    }

    private void setData(out ExpandableListViewAdapter mAdapter)
    {
        string urlholder;
        string url;
        string json;
        string time;
        string timestamp;
        string together;
        WebClient client1 = new WebClient();
        for (int i=0;i < length; i++)
        {
            List<string> listplaceholder = new List<string>();
            group.Add(names[i]);
            urlholder = Uri.EscapeDataString(names[i]);
            url = "**********";
            json = client1.DownloadString(url);
            JSONArray array2 = new JSONArray(json);
            int length2 = array2.Length();
            for (int j = 0; j < length2; j++)
            {
                JSONObject Element = array2.GetJSONObject(j);
                time=Element.GetString("wait");
                JSONObject TimeElement = array2.GetJSONObject(j);
                timestamp = TimeElement.GetString("created_at");
                timestamp=timestamp.Replace("T", " at ");
                int index = timestamp.IndexOf(".");
                if (index > 0)
                {
                    timestamp = timestamp.Substring(0, index);
                }
                together = time + " minutes posted at " + timestamp;
                listplaceholder.Add(together);
            }
            Mapout.Add(group[i], listplaceholder);


        }
        mAdapter = new ExpandableListViewAdapter(this, group, Mapout);
    }

}
}
```

This is my custom Expandable Base Adapter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Lang;

namespace DictionaryE
{
public class ExpandableListViewAdapter : BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    private List<string> listGroup;
    private Dictionary<string, List<string>> listChild;

    public ExpandableListViewAdapter(Context context, List<string> listGroup, Dictionary<string, List<string>> listChild)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.listGroup = listGroup;
        this.listChild = listChild;
    }
    public override int GroupCount
    {
        get
        {
            return listGroup.Count;
        }
    }

    public override bool HasStableIds
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        listChild.TryGetValue(listGroup[groupPosition], out result);
        return result[childPosition];
    }

    public override long GetChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return childPosition;
    }

    public override int GetChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        listChild.TryGetValue(listGroup[groupPosition], out result);
        return result.Count;
    }

    public override View GetChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            convertView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Children, null);
        }
        TextView textViewItem = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.DataValue);
        string content = (string)GetChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        textViewItem.Text = content;
        return convertView;
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetGroup(int groupPosition)
    {
        return listGroup[groupPosition];
    }

    public override long GetGroupId(int groupPosition)
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public override View GetGroupView(int groupPosition, bool isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            convertView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Groups, null);
        }
        string textGroup = (string)GetGroup(groupPosition);
        TextView textViewGroup = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Header);
        textViewGroup.Text = textGroup;
        return convertView;
    }

    public override bool IsChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return true;
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Could you please post your codes? And for `when I use .Filter with my ExpandableListViewAdapter mAdapter my code wont build.`, did you get any exception for that and in which line?

Comment: Sure I can post codes; Exception was IFilter is a method which is not valid in the given context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Filter is a method which is not valid in the given context.

To use the filter on your adapter, you need to let your adapter implements [`IFilterable`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.IFilterable/) interface:

```
public class ExpandableListViewAdapter : BaseExpandableListAdapter,IFilterable
{
  ...
}
```

Update:

If you have implemented the interface, by default the `Filter` is empty like below:

```
public class ExpandableListViewAdapter : BaseExpandableListAdapter,IFilterable
{
  ...
  Filter=>throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

That's why you are getting the exception. What needs to be done is to create a custom Filter class:

```
public class GroupFilter:Filter
{
    ExpandableListViewAdapter _adapter;
    public GroupFilter(ExpandableListViewAdapter adapter)
    {
        _adapter = adapter;
    }
    protected override FilterResults PerformFiltering(ICharSequence constraint)
    {
        var result = new FilterResults();
        // add the filtered items to FilterResults
        //convert net object to java object
        return result;
    }

    protected override void PublishResults(ICharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
    {
        //convert java object to Net object
        //Call _adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

And initialize the Filter in your adapter:

```
public class ExpandableListViewAdapter : BaseExpandableListAdapter,IFilterable
{
  ...
  public Filter Filter => new GroupFilter(this);
}
```

For a complete implementation sample of Filer, you can refer to Cheesebaron's demo [here](https://gist.github.com/Cheesebaron/9838325).

Comment: I was looking at that but what do I add in the method? Thats where I was confused. I was going to use adapter.Filter.InvokeFilter(e.NewText); Now when I use it however It doesnt work because the filter method in the adapter has nothing but throw new NotImplementedException();

Comment: I appreciate the answer! However I am getting lost in cheesebarons as his is a listview<Chemical> and mine is an expandable list view with string. i am trying to get around it but I am getting a lot of errors.

Comment: Sorry, when you have the time if you can just show me the jist of it? I keeping getting errors and am having a hard time.

Comment: Sorry for late response, I'll make a basic demo for you. Could you please tell me what do you want to filter exactly? I mean,what are your filter rules.

Comment: I am trying to filter out whatever they put int he search box. So whatever there input is, it will use that and filter the list to find the groups containing those characters. (I am trying to filter groups too not the children). Thank you!

Comment: You can find the demo I created from your codes here:[TestFilterDemo](https://github.com/elvisxia/TestFilterDemo). Please don't copy the codes directly, as I simply created fake data for use.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you!  Now my problem is after I search and get rid of the text my whole list just dissappears! but Ill look into it!

Comment: I dont know if I should post another question or just ask her. I am now using if and elseif trying to preserve the original adapter. Whenever I do the filter search it work but when I backspace I lose my original adapter

Comment: Please Create a new post together with detailed codes and reproduce steps in it.

Comment: Ive posted a new question

Comment: Hey I haven't heard from you in a while, just wondering if you can me with the other question.

Comment: Sorry, didn't work at weekend. I've post the answer, please have a check.